# I had a power outage. Now MySQL's lock file won't go away. What do you suggest?

Tags: linux, mysql, slackware, outage

I do freelance IT consulting for various clients, both in Toronto, Canada, and worldwide.

A client recently experienced a power failure.  Now they've been having various problems with a Slackware 12.0.0 machine which also acts as a DNS server.

One problem is that they can't log into phpMyAdmin.

I tried stopping and restarting MySQL.  But even when MySQL is stopped, the lock file stays around.

```
jasonspiro@cybertron:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop 
Shutting down MySQL. SUCCESS! 
jasonspiro@cybertron:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!
jasonspiro@cybertron:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
 ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock exists
jasonspiro@cybertron:~$ ls -l /var/lock/subsys/mysql 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 2012-07-05 16:18 /var/lock/subsys/mysql
```

Why is MySQL's lock file hanging around despite the fact that MySQL isn't running?

Can I simply stop MySQL, delete the lock file, and start MySQL again?

Are there any other steps that I should take next, or nothing?

**EDIT:**  A while after I asked this question, I noticed that [the way MySQL is installed on this machine seems wonky](https://serverfault.com/questions/405262/why-is-there-a-etc-init-d-mysql-file-on-this-slackware-machine-how-could-it-ha).  Also, I found out that the `/etc/init.d/mysql` script I found on this machine always creates a lock file when it starts MySQL and never deletes the file when it stops MySQL.  So this question turns out to be irrelevant to me.  Thank you, but I don't need more answers to this question.

Comment: Lock files are only removed during a graceful shutdown.  Power-failures do not qualify :-)

Comment: The lock is in /var/log/run

Comment: @AndrewSmith:  Thanks for your reply.  I don't have a /var/log/run directory.  Am I supposed to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do: `ls -al /var/lock/subsys`

Look for `mysql.pid`. Remove that.
Also remove `mysql.sock` if it exists.

If all else fails, [as root] use `updatedb ; locate <filename>`.  This is your friend in situations like this.

Try restarting MySQL using the init script. If that doesn't work, restore to a database checkpoint from an acceptable backup of the database.

If no database backups exist: Make a clone of this disk with `dd` ASAP. You may need to use some hard-core recovery procedures. Even if the MySQL service starts back up again, save the best known-good backup for a while, just in case.

Comment: MySQL starts up fine now.  No data was lost.  Thank you for the answer you posted above.

Comment: You are most welcome, best of luck to you on your project.

Comment: what is the lock state for anyways? this just happened to me.

Comment: @duckx, please see [this answer (on SF)](http://serverfault.com/a/279367/78702) and [this answer (on SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/748568/667301)